# Does output cache in ASP.net takes the fragment into consideration

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

What  happens when ASP.net output cache encounters a URL with a fragment ('#')? - Will it ignore it and cache the page as if it is a regular page without the fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

# isn't sent back to the server. So technically, it will never encounter one of those URLs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

> **The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the
>   URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no
>   participation from the server** — of course the server typically helps
>   to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the
>   processing of fragments. When an agent (such as a Web browser)
>   requests a resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the
>   server, **but does not send the fragment**. Instead, the agent waits for
>   the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the
>   resource according to the document type and fragment value.